# JQuery converting "option:contains" into an exact string value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I am getting a `select` option's `value` (literal `value` attribute) from JQuery, the problem is that it takes the first value it finds that simply "contains" that keyword.

For example, if I had a `select` with two options: Silver Division (`value=1`) and Silver (`value=2`), if I called the following line of code it would return (`value=1`) rather than (`value=2`)

```
var ranking = "Silver"; // hard-coded for example
var setIndex = $("#userElo" +" > option:contains(" + ranking + ")").val();
```

**Q:** I have been trying to search, with no success, for something like `option:equals` so that it only looks for exact string matches. I have tried various test-and-guess things like the following.

```
var setIndex = $("#userElo" + ID + " > option:contains" + ranking).val();
var setIndex = $("#userElo" + ID + " > option[text=" + ranking + "]").val();
var setIndex = $("#userElo" + ID + " > option[text=" + ranking).val();
```

Here is a **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ppuQ/)** on a simple scale showing the Silver Division and Silver issue.

I am running out of ideas though, so if anyone know of some syntax for this solution that'd be awesome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to select all of the options that may potentially match, then use the [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to narrow them down to those that do actually match the text you want. This should do it:

```
var ranking = "Silver";
var setIndex = $("#userElo > option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === ranking;
}).val();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I understand what you mean, but I cannot seem to get this to work on my **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ppuQ/1/)**. Am I implementing it wrong?

Comment: @Austin As abhitalks said, it's because there's no ID variable in your code. I didn't look at the fiddle, I just assumed that the code attempts in your question were using the correct selector. I'll edit my answer. EDIT: Here's the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ppuQ/2/).

Comment: AH thank you! I noticed I forgot to use `trim()` on the `$(this).text()` as well, as my db adds additional whitespace to values.